# Difficulty in integrating JQuery Slide Menu with existing mobile site

Tags: java, jquery, mobile

I have an existing mobile site written in Java and hosted on Tomcat for which I'm trying to integrate this slide menue

https://github.com/tegansnyder/JQuery-Mobile-Slide-Menu

However I'm having a very strange issue which seems to be specific to my Samsung Galaxy S3 browser as I'm not seeing the same on Chrome or Firefox.

When I click on one of my menu links in the slider menue, it redirects me to the URL I specified but adds a # symbol. For example

domain.mobi/#/help.jsp?helpsource=index.jsp

Whereas it should be

domain.mobi/help.jsp?helpsource=index.jsp

This effectively breaks the page as the slider menu on that page no longer works.

Any ideas?

Here is the code on my index.jsp

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" 
                   "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<c:set var="locale" value="en"/>
<c:if test="${not empty param.locale}">
  <c:set var="locale" value="${param.locale}"/>
</c:if>
<fmt:setLocale value="${locale}"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="chale"/>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/chale.tld" prefix="chale" %>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

 <link href="css/themes/jqmfb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="css/chale_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="css/jquery.mobile.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--Include JQM and JQ-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
 <script src="js/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>

        <!--JQM globals you can edit or remove file entirely... note it needs to be loaded     before jquerymobile js -->
<script src="js/jqm.globals.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<!--JQM SlideMenu-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm.slidemenu.css" />
<script src="js/jqm.slidemenu.js"></script>  
<title><fmt:message key="index.pagetitle"/></title>
</head>
<body>
<c:set var="pageVal" value="0"/>
<c:if test="${not empty param.page}">
<c:set var="pageVal" value="${param.page}"/> 
</c:if>



<div id="slidemenu">

    <div id="profile">

        <div class="profile_info"><strong>Chale</strong></div>
    </div>

    <h3>MENU</h3>

    <ul>
        <c:url var="finder" value="m/browse.jsp"/>
        <li><a href="${finder}"><img src="../img/smico4.png"><fmt:message key="index.optionflirtfinder"/></a></li>

        <c:url var="fav" value="m/favourites.jsp"/>
        <li><a href="${fav}"><img src="../img/smico4.png"><fmt:message key="general.favourites"/></a></li>


        <c:url var="message" value="m/messaging.jsp"><c:param name="messagesource" value="../index.jsp"/></c:url>
        <li><a href="${message}"><img src="../img/smico4.png"><fmt:message key="general.messages"><fmt:param value="${unreadMessages}"/></fmt:message></a></li>

        <c:url var="chat" value="chat/checkdetailsservlet"/>
        <li><a href="${chat}"><img src="../img/smico4.png"><fmt:message key="index.optionchatcentral"/></a></li>

        <c:url var="prof" value="m/profile.jsp"/>
        <li><a href="${prof}"><img src="../img/smico4.png"><fmt:message key="index.optionmyprofile"/></a></li>

        <c:url var="help" value="help.jsp"><c:param name="helpsource" value="index.jsp"/></c:url>
        <li><a href="${help}"><img src="../img/smico4.png"><fmt:message key="general.helpcentre"/></a></li>

    </ul>


</div>

<div data-role="page" id="main_page" data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-   update-page-padding="false">
        <a href="@" data-slidemenu="#slidemenu" data-slideopen="false" data-icon="smico" data-corners="false" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
        <h1>Chale</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Derek, yes that's exactly right. Sure, I will edit my question and add some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got what you are facing. `<a>` tags will be will be intercepted by jquery mobile to use AJAX to get the HTML/navigate the page instead of changing page directly.

It will generate the url with hash (#) to navigate the page. 
Ref: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html 
Search the keyword : hash

`domain.mobi/#/help.jsp?helpsource=index.jsp`

To fix this issue, you would add data-ajax="false" in the url.

```
<a href="${finder}" data-ajax="false"><img src="../img/smico4.png"><fmt:message key="index.optionflirtfinder"/></a>
```

If the link is linking to another site or domain you have to add `rel="external"` also.
Ref: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now. Any idea why it doesn't do it in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Hi Derek, please can you let me know your email address. I would like to contract you to do some work